# Finding day from two date columns

Tags: python, datetime, spyder

I have two columns with start and end dates;[A snippet of the columns][1]
S

```
ervice Start Day    Service Completion Day
2015-02-16  2015-02-16
2015-06-17  2015-06-18
2015-06-06  2015-06-06
2015-08-08  2015-08-08
2015-08-03  2015-08-21
2015-07-25  2015-07-25
2015-08-17  2015-08-17
2015-07-30  2015-09-24
```

I want to calculate the difference between all these dates,row-wise and place them in another column.

I tried doing it in ths manner;

```
Df['Service Completion Day'] = date(Df['Service Completion Day'])

Df['Service Request Day'] = date(Df['Service Request Day'])

Df.assign(Days = Df['Service Completion Day'] - Df['Service Request Day'])
```

But this is not working.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do not add images, add the content in your question.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As input, you are having two strings, e.g. `'2015-02-12'` and `'2015-02-16'`. You should parse them into `datetime.date` objects and then calculate the difference.

For example:

```
import datetime

date_string_1 = '2015-02-12'
date_string_2 = '2015-02-16'

date1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string_1, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
date2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string_2, '%Y-%m-%d').date()

print (date2-date1)  # prints: 4 days, 0:00:00

difference_in_days = (date2-date1).days

print(difference_in_days)  # prints: 4
```

Comment: @AdhirajChattopadhyay OK, how do they affect the answer?

Comment: @AdhirajChattopadhyay Well, repeat the above for each of the rows.